# Adding different classes to anchor in navigation menu

Tags: menus, navigation, links, sub-menu

Is this possible?

I want to add different classes to the anchors, so not the same on all anchors. How can I do this?

PS: I am using this:

```
function add_nav_class($output) {
    $output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="your-class"', $output, 1);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

But I want to add different classes to the links...

So like this:

```
<li><a class="1></a></li>
<li><a class="2></a></li>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can achieve this using `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects($objects, $args) {
    foreach($objects as $key => $item) {
        $objects[$key]->classes[] = 'my-class';
    }
    return $objects;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);
```

The only problem is that these classes will be added to `li` elements and not to links directly. But it's default WordPress behavior and I don't think you should change it.

If you really have to change it, it is still possible:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // you can put your if statements in here (use item, depth and args in conditions)
    if ( $depth == 1 ) {
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="level-1-menu" ', $item_output, 1);
    } else if ( $depth == 2 )
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="level-2-menu" ', $item_output, 1);
    }
    // .. and so on
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Comment: You say it's possible, but than you say it's adding it to the list item? That is no answer? I want them directly in to the `anchor`.

Comment: But what's the differce? You can use it in CSS like `.my-class a` instead of `a.my-class`. jQuery selectors works like that too.

Comment: The difference is that I want to add icons, using a font. If I put them in a list, it won't show it the way I want. If I put in the anchor, it works. That is because it puts them `:before` them. That's why I am asking you this. FYI: the code that i have inputted in my post is putting a class in to anchors, but I want different classes for the anchors, so not one for all...

Comment: I know, what your code does (although it does it in very ugly way). You haven't tell the reason why you want it in your question though, so my solution was the best for your question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case, if I want the other anchors to have a different class, I have to add a 2 instead of the 1, is that correct? What do I have to do for that?

Comment: Add 2? What do you mean?

Comment: Just what I mean in my first post... I want to give each anchor a different class. How do I do that? Now, I am giving all anchors the same class...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer: "you can put your if statements in here (use item, depth and args in conditions)"

Comment: So like what? I don't know what you mean with depth and args... Like this? `if #list-item-1 a.addClass(blabla)` or something?

Comment: Well, it's your code, so I'm not able to tell what conditions do you need in there. If you know PHP it should be easy now (and it's not about WordPress anymore). If you don't know PHP, you shouldn't mess with it at all.

Comment: I will find it out myself. Will mess with it, even without the help. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Why use preg_replace when you can use str_replace

Comment: @Dev result of simplifying the code for SE. originally the preg_replace pattern was more complicated to take care of some specific stuff. You’re right - here you can easily use str_replace

Comment: Which is better. preg or str

Comment: @Dev it’s hard to say which is better. str is simpler, so it will be a little bit faster, but - the gain on one operation is so small, you won’t see it.

Answer (score 5):

you can follow the below Steps :

Step 1 : In the wp-admin, go to Appearance -> Menus,put the class on the menu item here "CSS Classes (optional)". If you can't see the "CSS Classes (optional)" in the menu item, then there is "Screen Option" in the right top of the screen and there are the options "CSS Class" under "Show advanced menu properties".

Step 2: Under your them folder/function.php add below code :

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $classes     = implode(' ', $item->classes);
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="'.$classes.'"', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;
 }
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Hope above code works for you , let me know if still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {

    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ){
    $classes['class'] = 'active ';
    }
    $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="'.$classes['class'].'"', $item_output, 1);
    return $item_output;

 }
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```